# $u=f(x,y)$ and the partial derivatives are themselves differentiable functions of $x$ and $y$ (Typo?)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, gre-exam

I am really not sure whether this question can be posted in MSE or not, but hopefully can be. If not, kindly do not downvote, but suggest me to delete it from here and post it somewhere else.

While reading an old scanned book (not clear/blurred), I have found this multiple choice question:

[image]

[image]

Which, using Latex, is:

If $u=f(x,y)$ and the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ are themselves differentiable functions of $x$ and $y$, there partial derivatives are denoted by:

I. $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$

II. $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x}$

III. $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}$

IV. $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}$

Which of the above are always equal?

(A) I and II

(B) II and III

(C) III and IV

(D) I and III

(E) II and IV

---

The solution is:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Which, using Latex, is:

(B)

If $u=f(x,y)$, and if $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x},\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}$ are continuous, then $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y \partial x}$; that is, the order of differentiation is immaterial.

---

Now, my question is; in the problem statement, "If $u=f(x,y)$ and the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\color{red}{\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}}$ are themselves ...", should not it be "If $u=f(x,y)$ and the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\color{green}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}$ are themselves ..."?

I have included the solution so one may find if this is typo or it is okay.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS.

Comment: Yes, it's an unfortunate typo.  And we really need to know what they mean by "differentiable." It is not sufficient just to say partial derivatives exist. You need the stronger sense of differentiability or continuity of the second-order partial derivatives.

Comment: If $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ is differentiable, it means that $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ exists. No problem with that sir. The problem is; is it $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ or $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$?

Comment: I already said it was obviously a typo. But, no, you need *more* than existence of the second-order partial derivatives. Crummy question.

Comment: @TedShifrin What do we need so that the order of differentiation will be immaterial, other than the existence of the second derivatives? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari: See Wikipedia, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Theorem_of_Schwarz]) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives#Sufficiency_of_twice-differentiability), for two variants. Curiously enough, the question in your book seems to refer to one of these variants, but the answer to the other!